# undefined method `each' for 4294:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, each

I updated from Rails 3.2.3 to 3.2.8 yesterday.

this script worked up until yesterday. now i get this error:

```
/daily_counts.rb:32:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for 4294:Fixnum (NoMethodError)


top_posters = Load.where("created_at >= '#{today}' AND comments NOT LIKE '%Post%'").count(:all, group: "user_id", order: "COUNT(*) DESC", limit: 8)
output += "Loadmax Totals\n\s\sAll Avaliable Trucks: #{alltrucks}\n\s\sAll Avaliable Loads: #
{allloads}\n\s\sTodays Loads: #{loads}\n\s\sTodays Trucks: #{trucks}\n\nLoadmax Top Posters\n\s\sPostEverywhere: #{posteverywhere}\n\s\sPostOnce: #{postonce}\n"
posters = "\s\s"

LINE 32: Below
top_posters.each do |k,v|
  company_name = Company.find(User.find(k).company_id).name unless k.nil?
  poster = {
    name: company_name,
    posts: v
  }
  poster[:name] = 'MISC' if poster[:name].nil?
  posters += "#{poster[:name]}: #{poster[:posts]}\n\s\s"
end
output += posters.chop.chop.chop
output += "\n\s\s"
users = "\s\s"
```

with the full script. it is exspose to send an email that look like this:

```
Total Active Loads/Trucks for Today or FutureLast 24 hours Users Logged In: 0

Loadmax Totals
  All Avaliable Trucks: 409
  All Avaliable Loads: 150799
  Todays Loads: 78316
  Todays Trucks: 169

Loadmax Top Posters
  PostEverywhere: 70374
  PostOnce: 2974
  AMTransportServices.Inc: 2130
  TNT Trucking of the Carolinas LLC: 1099
  JM: 425
  BOYD: 412
  DANDL: 327
  bijDHhgvsiKBa: 180
  MTB: 177
  Ultra Logistics: 131

  digihaul@digihaul.com
   Last Login Date 2014-06-16
   Logins: 23
```

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: yeah just have to recode. something happened and now the original isnt working any longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `each' for 4294:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

The error is due to your **`top_posters`** is 4294 which is an **`integer`** because currently it returns a **`count`**.So you **`can't iterate`** or **`loop`** through an integer.

If you want loop through **`top_posters`** it should be perhaps an **`array`** or a **`hash`**.

So you need to fix your query according to your requirements such that the **`top_posters`** is an **`array`** or a **`hash`**.